# Best way to store a list (of users) that have joined a temporary event in a database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a website application (javascript, html/css, php, I am using a MySQL database for the back-end) where you can create an "event" (ex: basketball game, birthday party, etc..) at a location on a map, and then other users can "join" the event. So when someone views the site, they can look at the map and see the different events that others have created as well as a list of users who have "joined" the event. If a user creates an account on the site, they can then opt to join the event as well if they want. These events are temporary, meaning that I could create an event at 4 pm this Saturday for a volleyball game at my local park, so after 4pm on Saturday it wont be on the map anymore for any user to see. I would also like to implement an "event history" feature that will allow a user to also view the events they have joined/participated in in the past, however that is not my main concern at the moment.

This is my first real project using a database, at least one where I am creating the schema for it. I know that storing a list of users for each event may not be the best/most efficient way to do this, but I am having trouble finding out how better to approach this. Here is an EXTREMELY rough schema diagram (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoJ1x.png) that obviously is not finished, I just wanted to get down the main data that I'll be storing. The confusion I am having is with the 'Joiners' field in the Events table

Should I create a temporary table for each event that is created and add a new entry for when a new user joins, and then delete that table once that event has finished? I feel like there is a simple/common solution for a problem like this that I just am not finding/thinking of. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think creating multiple temporary tables is the way to go. I would suggest creating a single table that links events to joiners, and adding/deleting rows as needed.

Comment: You use a third table where each row contains a user id and event id.

Answer (score 1):

You have a many to many relationship between events and joiners, where many joiner can participate multiple events.

The typical way to represent this relationship in a relational database is to create a thrid table, called a *bridge* table - say `user_events`. Each record in the table stands for a user participating an event, referenced by their id in referral tables `events` and `users`.

```
create table events (
    event_id int primary key,
    ...
);

create table users(
    user_id int primary key,
    ...
);

create table event_users (
    event_id int,
    user_id int,
    primary key(event_id, user_id),
    foreign key (event_id) references events(event_id),
    foreign key (user_id)  references users(user_id)
);
```

This is a typical, robust design, and you should not worry about performance beforehand. Well-defined design sets for efficient queries, that will take advantage of the foreign key relationships when you will join the tables.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you are saying. So for example, say user_id #1 creates an event_id #1. and then user_id #2, #3, and #4 all join that event #1. The event_users table would then contain all 4 users, all each linked with event #1?

What about when the event has finished, do I need to delete all those entries that pertained to that specific event?

Comment: I would not delete; just set a flag on the `events` table that indicates when the event is finished. If you ever want to delete, then you should add option `on delete cascade` to the foreign key. Then you just have to `delete` from `events`, and all children rows in the bridge table will be deleted as well.

Comment: Ahh I see, so I should add a flag field (i.e boolean) to the events table that indicates whether the event is an active event or not, and I can leave the event_users table alone?

Comment: @actuallife The event has a date (or a start and end date), so there's no need for a separate flag. You can always tell by the date whether the event is finished.

Comment: @chrisg you mentioned that you want participants to be able to view their history. Deleting stuff rarely assists that ambition.